# Defining Javascript locales globally

Tags: javascript

Javascript has some function for locale operations like `localeCompare`, `toLocaleUpperCase` etc...

Is it possible to define a global locale to be used by these functions instead of passing this variable each time.

Comment: why can't you set a global variable or read the local from the `lang` attribute as you have suggested? it's unclear what is the actual question..

Comment: can use `window.navigator.language` will return `en-US` i.e. preferred language of the user/browser. can store in a global variable to use in application.

Comment: "why can't you set a global variable or read the local from the lang"  Ofcourse this is possible if I pass the variable to the functions each time. I want to define it once and use locale with out declaring it to the functions. If possible

Comment: If you set the locale to a fixed one, this would render the whole mechanism useless. The whole point is that you can use UTC everywhere and then let the frontend do the locale formatting stuff without any worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to define it globally.

Wrapping with other custom functions and setting global variables that seamlessly passing argument may be solution.